# Вырезать часть строки по разделителю

Tags: python, python-3.x

На вход программе подается строка текста, в которой буква «h» встречается минимум два раза. Как удалить из этой строки первое и последнее вхождение буквы «h», а также все символы, находящиеся между ними?

Я сделала вот так:

```
s = input()
total = 0
for i in s:
    total += s.count(i)
print(total)
#или print max(total)
```

но я не понимаю как сделать, чтобы для каждого символа создавался счетчик Я не смогла решить эту задачу, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Простите я перепутала задание, вот задание:

Comment: На вход программе подается строка текста. Напишите программу, которая выводит на экран символ, который появляется наиболее часто.

Формат входных данных 
На вход программе подается строка текста. Текст может содержать строчные и заглавные буквы английского и русского алфавита, а также цифры.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести символ, который появляется наиболее часто.

Примечание 1. Если таких символов несколько, следует вывести последний по порядку символ.

Примечание 2. Следует различать заглавные и строчные буквы, а также буквы русского и английского алфавита.

Comment: воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" под вопросом. Вопрос должен быть сформулирован в теле вопроса, а не в комментариях...

Comment: @Снежана заголовок вопроса не соответствует самому вопросу... так и должно быть?

Comment: Jack_oS Я перепутала задание, я в комментариях написала настоящее задание

Comment: тогда лучше оформить вторым вопросом с новым текстом задания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно найти индексы символа 'h' в исходной строке:

```
sep_indexes = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(text) if char == separator]
```

и соединить то, что перед первым 'h' с тем, что после последнего 'h':

```
begin = text[:sep_indexes[0]]
end = text[sep_indexes[-1]+1:]

result = begin + end
```

Все вместе:

```
def cut_text(text, separator):
    sep_indexes = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(text) if char == separator]

    begin = text[:sep_indexes[0]]
    end = text[sep_indexes[-1]+1:]

    return begin + end

text = 'foohbarhspam'
separator = 'h'

new_text = cut_text(text, separator)
print(new_text)
```

напечатает `foospam`

Answer (score 1):

Можно найти первое (`text.find('h')`) и последнее (`text.rfind('h')`) вхождение символа `h` в строку. Затем отрезать от строки начало до первого символа и конец после последнего. Склеить их:

```
text = input()

#             первая 'h'            последняя 'h'
#           --------------         ---------------
print(text[:text.find('h')] + text[text.rfind('h') + 1:])
#     ---------------------   --------------------------
#     начало текста до 'h'      конец текста после 'h'
```

Более изощрённое решение - регулярное выражение `h.*h`. Символы `h` сопоставятся сами с собой в строке. `.*` - означает "любое количество любых символов".

Регулярные выражения жадные: они ищут самый длинный фрагмент для сопоставления. Это значит что первая `h` в выражении сопоставится с первым вхождением буквы `h` в строке, последняя `h` в выражении - с последней `h` в строке.

`re.sub` заменяет найденное сопоставление на второй свой аргумент. Второй аргумент - пустая строка, то есть мы выбрасываем то что нашли:

```
import re

text = input()

print(re.sub('h.*h', '', text))
```

Оба варианта работают одинаково (если в строке есть хотя бы две `h`):

> '1h2h3h4' -> '14'